# xamarin.forms - text binding to EntryRenderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, binding, xamarin.forms

I am making xamarin.forms application. One requirement of my project is that Focus Entry should not pop system keyboard. So I made a Custom Entry with this guide: [Keyboard disabled guide](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/05/19/a-keyboard-disabled-entry-control-in-xamarin-forms/)

Everything works very good. But there comes another problem..

If I make simple binding:

```
<local:SoftKeyboardDisabledEntry 
            Placeholder="Keyboard disabled Entry Control..." 
            x:Name="SoftKeyboardDisabledEntry" 
            Text="{Binding TestValue}"/>
```

it does't react.. (I am sure that ViewModel is working just fine, because 'normal' Entry is working fine)

So. **Question is**, is there a way to make binding to this field?

---

Code of Custom Entry:
in NewXamarinProject.Droid namespace

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SoftKeyboardDisabledEntry), typeof(SoftkeyboardDisabledEntryRenderer))]
namespace NewXamarinProject.Droid
{
    public class SoftkeyboardDisabledEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                ((SoftKeyboardDisabledEntry)e.NewElement).PropertyChanging += OnPropertyChanging;
            }

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                ((SoftKeyboardDisabledEntry)e.OldElement).PropertyChanging -= OnPropertyChanging;
            }

            // Disable the Keyboard on Focus
            this.Control.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanging(object sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs propertyChangingEventArgs)
        {
            // Check if the view is about to get Focus
            if (propertyChangingEventArgs.PropertyName == VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                // incase if the focus was moved from another Entry
                // Forcefully dismiss the Keyboard 
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.Control.WindowToken, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in NewXamarinProject namespace:

```
namespace NewXamarinProject 
{
    public class SoftKeyboardDisabledEntry : Entry
    {
    }
}
```

---

EDIT/SOLUTION: This code works properly, I made this Entry once again and it is working, I cant explain what was bad.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I am not sure if this would work but you can give it a try:

```
public class SoftKeyboardDisabledEntry : Entry
{
    public static readonly new BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Text",
       returnType: typeof(string),
       declaringType: typeof(SoftKeyboardDisabledEntry),
       defaultValue: default(string));

    public new string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added this to code, and unfortunatelly looks like it does not change anything :/.. Implementing ONLY your code should influence on binding property? or should I add to code something else?

Comment: and shouldn't in your code be somewhere 'TestValue' ?

Comment: The code I posted just overrides the Text property of Entry. Rest should behave the same. You can try to change property's name from "Text" to something else and use that in XAML. You can also add a breakpoint at getter/setter to see if its executing the code. Also look into OnElementPropertyChanged method. You might need to implement that.

Comment: Yes. I used debugger and code isn't even executed. I guess OnElementPropertyChanged method should be used to trigger that code? Could you tell me where i should implement it?

Comment: ok, I made this field once again and Binding started to works (without your code) ..... lost planty of time.